# Changing ListBox SelectedValuePath throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I wrote a quick application for an article on CodeProject (full article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele). You can download the source code for this question directly from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/671544/SelectedValue_and_SelectedItem_demo-noexe.zip)).

It's a very simple window that has a ListBox with simple objects (3 properties: 2 strings, 1 int).

```
public class MyShape
{
    public string ShapeType  { get; set; }
    public string ShapeColor { get; set; }
    public int    ShapeSides { get; set; }
}
```

I'm setting the `SelectedValuePath` in the code behind so a user can select a property from a combobox, and see the current `SelectedValue` in a Label.

The ComboBox is set to an object of type:

```
public class PropertyObject
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

Both properties are strings, and so, should be valid as input for the `SelectedValuePath`.

I'm setting the value like this:

```
private void ShapeClassPropertiesCmbx_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmbx = (ComboBox)sender;
        PropertyObject prop_ob = ((PropertyObject)cmbx.SelectedItem);
        string name = prop_ob.PropertyName;
        var item_index = SourceListBox.SelectedIndex;
        //SourceListBox.SelectedValuePath = null;       // without this, we get a null exceptions when going from string to int properties for some reason.
        SourceListBox.SelectedValuePath = name;
        SourceListBox.SelectedIndex = item_index;
    }
```

(If you download the code, it's line 79 on the MainWindow.xaml.cs).

The exception happens when I change the selected value from a `string` to an `int`. 
To avoid confusion, both will be `string` representation of the property to show.

To reproduce the error, comment out line 79. Run the demo:

- Select any of the first 2 string properties on the SelectedValuePath combobox (2nd one).
- Change the selection on the listbox (you should see the `SelectedValue` changing accordingly)
- Change the selection in the 2nd combobox to the int property (which is a string representation really).
  An exception is thrown with the error: **"Input string was not in a correct format"**

The weird thing is: if you repeat the steps, but select the int property first, it works fine. Changing to a string then, still works fine. Back to the int, exception is thrown.

Setting the `SelectedValuePath` to null before setting it seems to solve the issue. Any suggestions why thy exceptions is thrown and what's the issue?

**Edit**:
Here's a new demo with more property types. It will also show what error is thrown, and track the `SelectedIndex`: [Download new demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1v3pii1gnkbdrm/SelectedValue%20and%20SelectedItem%202.zip).

Comment: If I comment out line 78, 'item_index' is no longer defined. Was I supposed to comment out line 81 as well? Ah, I see. You meant line 79. Trying this again....

Comment: Argh, My code was out of sync it seems. ok, line 79. The one that is commented out in my class above here (it's not commented out on the demo, because it'll crash it). I'll update the question as well.

Comment: Will be interesting to see your final project when you've got it all wrapped up!

Comment: That is the final project :) it was meant to help people visualize the difference between SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, etc. The workaround is to set it to null, but I'm still rather curious at the exception's cause, because it makes no sense to me...

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like item_index is undefined if line 78 is commented out. **Edit:** Ooops! Was supposed to be line 79.

**Edit:** Ok, the problem is that SelectedValuePath is simply expecting to convert a string to a string when you tell it expect a string. But when you tell it that it that it's 'value' is supposed to be an integer, it expects you to pass in a string version of some kind of integer. It can then convert this into the appropriate *integer* value. Your still passing in a name, and it can't convert that to an integer and tells you so. If you step through the code and change name to something like "2", instead of "ShapeSides", it will run correctly. I recommend checking for the index of the value chosen, and setting name = SelectedValue.ToString() if the type is supposed to be a string or name = SelectedIndex.ToString() if it's supposed to be an integer.

```
    switch (SourceListBox.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            name = SourceListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            break;
        case 2:
            name = SourceListBox.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Yep, was supposed to be 79, I've updated it. (must have added a line in my code after submission)

Comment: Hope this was of some use.

Comment: Hey, yes and no. I expanded the demo to other properties types, and received different results. I've opened another question in order not to mess this one up. I'll clean the code and post here an updated demo. My problem with this solution is that it depends on the switch and the items, and so will not work on a class that you didn't write, or don't know what it includes.

Comment: The switch statement is merely a suggestion to illuminate what's going wrong. I wouldn't implement things this particular way. Just answering the original question. Will look at your new question.