# How do the internals of SelectedValuePath work (on combobox/listbox)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to solve another question of mine ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510426/changing-listbox-selectedvaluepath-throws-an-exception)), and I'm stuck on the internals of changing the `SelectedValuePath` in code.

It seems that depending on what I'm changing from/to, different things will happen.
I've researched SO, debugged it, and even tried to find the offending code in the MS dll's using dotPeek, but for no avail so far.

If I'm changing from any type of property to a string property, it works ok.

Changing from string to int will throw an exception.

Changing from bool to int depends:

- If the property was false, the selected index will change to 0, and the selected value will change to false (not an int, as it was supposed to be)
- If the property was true, the selected index will change to -1, and the selected value will be null.

My assumption is that somewhere someone is trying to parse something, and depending on what happens, the results might or might not work.

Since `SelectedValuePath` receieves strings as input, and just sets the `SelectedValue` to whatever they are pointing at. I would expect that when changing this the `SelectedItem` will not change, and that the correct value will show. I did not expect to get this myriad of different results/exceptions/behaviors ...

The only thing That comes to mind is that the type of `SelectedValue` is set to whatever the property that `SelectedValuePath` points at, and then when it changes, it might encounter a wrong type...

As a workaround, setting the `SelectedValuePath` to null before setting it to a new property seems to work (avoiding any exceptions being thrown).

**Edit**:

I've updated the project with some more types, and you can find it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1v3pii1gnkbdrm/SelectedValue%20and%20SelectedItem%202.zip). 
The offending bit is in a Try/Catch block, and extra information is shown whenever something weird happens.

**question 1**: The behavior that puzzles me is: Changing from string to any other type (once you have selected an item), will throw an exception, and the `SelectedValue` will not change anymore (setting it to the default will fix this problem).

Why is the `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format` thrown, and what was being changed??
(I have expected that changing the `SelectedValuePath` willsimply "reset" the `SelectedValue` to the new object/type)

Also, changing the `SelectedValuePath` will reset the SelectedIndex in most cases to either -1, or 0.
**Question 2**: why is the index changed?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but too much for a comment

How are you using SelectedValuePath?

For example if you are binding it to a TextBlock Text then it expects string.
It does not make sense to me to change the type of a SelectedValuePath
For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=employeeListBox, 
                      Path=SelectedValue}"
```

Not going to download and debug your code but this simple example does not throw an exception for me

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    lbNoBinding.SelectedValuePath = "StrMix";
    lbNoBinding.DisplayMemberPath = "StrMix";
}
public class MixedType
{
    public string StrMix { get { return "strMix"; } }
    public bool BoolMix { get { return true; } }
}
private List<MixedType> mixedTypes = new List<MixedType>() { new MixedType(), new MixedType() };
public List<MixedType> MixedTypes
{
    get { return mixedTypes; }
}

private void btnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {                
        lbNoBinding.SelectedValuePath = "BoolMix";
        lbNoBinding.DisplayMemberPath = "BoolMix";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting remark. It was used like this: <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=SourceListBox, Path=SelectedValue}" > . I then removed this label from the Xaml, to see if it makes a difference, but I'll get the same exception when I go from string to int.

Comment: Label Content expects string.

Comment: Comment out lines 94 & 95 in the xaml (both bind to SelectedValue), so now nothing binds to the selected value (not being used anywhere else for anything else) ... same exception, same behavior.

Comment: Cheers, I've used your code (only binding to a listbox since a label doesn't have `SelectedValuePath`, here's the exception your code throws the first time it's run: `A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.` (assuming you select an item on the listbox, so it's set before you click the button)

Comment: As stated in my answer it does not throw an exception for me.